# Postgresql with c3p0 - failover

Tags: postgresql, c3p0, failover

We're using currently c3p0 with postgresql.

Does c3p0 supports any fail-over mechanisms (no info in documentation so I assume that unfortunately no)?

I've found that mysql,oracle and ms sql supports some failover options in jdbc url, e.g. `jdbcUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://mainserver:1433;failoverPartner=backupserver;`

Are pgpool and pgpool-II only posibilities for postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in failover in either the JDBC driver or the PostgreSQL core

Other options besides pgpool-II are:

- [pgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer)
- [HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.sourceforge.net/) (although I'm not sure how active that still is)

A complete(?) overview of all solutions is available in the Postgres wiki:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Answer (score 9):

As of Version 9.2-1000 (2012-09-27) the postgres jdbc4 drivers support failover urls (although it isn't well documented in the api)
[postgres jdbc Changelog](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#contributors_9.2-1002)

As:

```
jdbc:postgresql://masterHost:port,slaveHost:port/db_name
```

Comment: There's some documentation at the bottom of: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html , `targetServerType` and `Connection Fail-over` are interesting.