# c3p0 Java Database Pooling, failover configuration

Tags: java, database-connection, c3p0

When a database is down then automatically the ip and port switch to another db server.

How should I configure c3p0 connection pooling of my web apps to follow this Database failover mechanism?

Currently, I am using c3p0, however in the last db failover, pool connections failed to reestablished.

Comment: Which database are you using? Some support failover JDBC URLs. e.g., `jdbc:postgresql://masterHost:port,slaveHost:port/db_name`. ([Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080050/postgresql-with-c3p0-failover/18543908))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reestablished after a failing request.
Attributes that helps to come over as soon as possible

- `p:testConnectionOnCheckin="true"`
- `p:preferredTestQuery="SELECT @@VERSION"`
- `p:acquireRetryAttempts="10"`